# How to display actual values using .format()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have lists `a1, a2, ... , a16` with certain values.

For example:

```
a1 = [1, 17, 33, 49, 65, 81, 97]
```

Then I'm creating a dictionary which makes use of these lists:

```
dct = {'0110': a1}
```

And then I try to create a reference to the variables using the following:

```
x = 1
x2 = 'a{0}'.format(x)
```

However when I `print(x2)` the value being returned is `a1` and not `[1, 17, 33, 49, 65, 81, 97]`

How do I get the actual output of the original `a1`?

Comment: Can you provide the steps to reproduce the problem? i.eShow the code to create your variables, construct your list, run your command x2 =... and then your print statements ? and then tell us what you expect to be shown

Comment: Your description of the question is not at all clear. Try explaining it a little better.

Comment: I'm just updating the question.

Comment: Use a dictionary instead

Comment: @hspandher I updated.

Comment: @cricket_007 similar, but still quite far for beginners.

Comment: The point is that if you remove the format method, you have the same question

Comment: Try using print(exec(x2))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the variable `x2` i.e (`x2 = 'a{0}.format(x)`) - you are creating a new variable `x2` as a string which contains the letters of your variable name, not as an actual reference to the variable.

If you want to get the value of your variable based on a string, you need to access the `globals()` dictionary

```
>>> a1 = 1
>>> a2 = 2
>>> mylist = [a1, a2]
>>> x = 1
>>> x2 = 'a{0}'.format(x)
>>> print(x2)
a1
>>> print(globals()[x2])
1
```

Comment: And after the case :) Thanks :)

Comment: This is works, but almost never the right approach. better to create a dict like `{'a1': 1}`